# ternary operator in php with echo value

Tags: php, operator-keyword, ternary

I want to write the following code in ternary operator. I tried in many way but it does not work at all.

```
<?php 

if(isset($options['footer_txt_color'])) {

    echo $options['footer_txt_color'];

} else {

    echo "#ffffff";

}

?>
```

Comment: *I tried in many way* I don't see a single one, please show us your attempts

Comment: It has been set duplicated but the best link, given the question, would have been this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16405986/inline-php-html-ternary-if

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Use this code

```
echo (isset($options['footer_txt_color'])) ? $options['footer_txt_color'] : '#ffffff';
```

Answer (score 4):

It should be like this:

```
<?php echo (isset($options['footer_txt_color'])) ? $options['footer_txt_color'] : "#ffffff"; ?>
```